# symfony2 url too long

Tags: php, symfony

i have this problem:

I created a link in my template as:

```
<div class="four columns alpha colform gestmtop">
        <h4 class="labelform">STAMPA REPORT</h4>
        <select name="" id="stampa-select">
            <option value='etichette'>Etichette</option>
            <option value='lista1'>Lista 1</option>
            <option value='lista2'>Lista 2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
<div class="four columns"><a href="#"  onclick='openStampaPfd();' class="gestg">STAMPA</a></div>
<div id="foo"></div>

function openStampaPfd(){

        var valSelected = $("#stampa-select").val();

        // alert(valSelected);
        var table = $('#anagrafica_datatable').DataTable();
        var ids=[];
        table.column(0, { search:'applied' } ).data().each(function(value, index) {
            ids.push(value);
        });

        if (valSelected==='lista1'){
            $("#foo").append("<a href='"+Routing.generate('anagrafica_lista_pdf',{ids: ids})+"'>Report Lista</a>");
        }else if (valSelected==='lista2'){
            $("#foo").append("<a href='"+Routing.generate('anagrafica_lista2_pdf',{ids: ids})+"'>Report Lista2</a>");
        }else if (valSelected==='etichette'){
            $("#foo").append("<a href='"+Routing.generate('anagrafica_etichette_pdf',{ids: ids})+"'>Report Etichette</a>");
            //window.open ('/example/stampa_etichette_clienti.php','_blank',false)
        }
        ///example/stampa_etichette_clienti.php
    };
```

in my controller the related action is:

```
/**
 * Print Anagrafica PDF.
 *
 * @Route("/anagraficaEtichettePdf/{ids}", name="anagrafica_etichette_pdf", options={"expose"=true})
 * @Method("POST")
 */

public function anagraficaEtichettePdfAction($ids){

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT a
FROM KritekGestionaleBundle:Anagrafica a WHERE a.id IN ('.$ids.')');

    $html = $this->renderView('KritekGestionaleBundle:Anagrafica:anagraficaEtichettePdf.html.twig', array('anagraficheList'=>$query->getResult()));

    return new Response(
        $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html),
        200,
        array(
            'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
            'charset' => 'UTF-8',
        )
    );
}
```

the problem is:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access  /app_dev.php/anagrafica/anagraficaEtichettePdf/00006,00007,00008,00009,00010,00011,00012,00013,00014,00015,00016,00017,00018,00019,00020,00021,00022,00023,00024,00025,00026,00027,00028,00029,00030,00031,.........(over 4000)
```

how can I solve the problem of url too long?
There is another way to solve the problem?
thanks!

Comment: 00006,00007,00008,00009... What mean these numbers?

Comment: sorry, are customer id filtered from jquery datatable

Comment: seems that `ids` in `Routing.generate('anagrafica_lista_pdf',{ids: ids})` is much to long. sure that u need all of these ids in your url? what are these ids are telling you?

Comment: ids contains all the id column of the grid datatables.net to do export in pdf. I only use the id in the grid even after it is filtered